# Tools for comparing logo fonts

Tags: fonts, logo

I'm starting with a logo design and want to know what tools are available that an quickly compare different fonts.  Take the word "Google" for example how can i quickly compare how it appears using different fonts such as Helvetica, Calibri, San Serif etc?

I looked at Typetester but that website can only compare 3 fonts at a time.  Looking for something that can do alot more than 3...

Thanks

Comment: On a humorous note: whatever the logo is, it is probably helvetica. If not, then arial.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure a bunch of font organizing programs would let you do just that.

There's [Font Book](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2509) for Mac, which is what I used to use.

I recently heard about [TypeDNA](http://www.typedna.com/) from one of these stackexchange websites actually. TypeDNA is a standalone application but it also allows you to connect it right into some Adobe products which is really neat.

There's so many of these programs out there.

(Sorry for the short answer I'm in quite busy this weekend, I'll try to expand on this later.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  Just looking for something that's free and on Windows.  Doesn't need to be fancy or anything, just a visual tool for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Most type foundries and distributor web sites let you mock up type using their online tools. Myfonts, for instance, lets you type a phrase, pick a type size, and then have it render in all available fonts.

Do note that randomly picking fonts to go with a company logo isn't usually the way to go about doing it. You'll typically want to have some idea of the typefaces' relevance during the design process so that you aren't spending time spinning wheels looking at 100 different fonts.

Comment: I agree - Do you have any references re typeface relevance?

Comment: If you don't have any formal typography training, I'd suggest starting with the book *Stop Stealing Sheep and learn how type works*. It's a quick read and a great overview of the world of type selection.